# Node JS Parallel DB Call

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, asynchronous

I've got a piece of code where I need to create a MySQL Connection and fire 3 queries on different tables. I'm trying to use a combination of async waterfall (for creating the connection and passing to the query execution) and parallel (to fire the queries). However, I'm at my wits end on how to collect the output in a single json.

The call is as follows:

```
  var finalJson = {};

  async.waterfall([
    function(callback){
        var connection = dbModel.init();
        callback(null, connection);
    },
    function(connection, callback){
      async.parallel([
        function(callback){
          dbModel.fetchA(connection, combineJson);
        },
        function(callback){
          dbModel.fetchB(connection, combineJson);
        },
        function(callback){
          dbModel.fetchC(connection, combineJson);
        }
      ]);
      callback();
    }
  ], function (err, result) {
  });

  function combineJson(obj){
    for(var key in obj){
      finalJson[key] = obj[key];
    }
    console.log(finalJson);
    return finalJson;
  }
```

The fetch function looks like this:

```
var fetchA = function(connection, callback){
    connection.query('SELECT * from A limit 1', function(err, rows, fields) {
        if(err) throw err;
        callback(rows[0]);
    });
}
```

The `combineJson` function is able to `console.log` the `finalJson` variable but when I access it from outside the `async.parallel` block, its undefined.

Comment: You must call the callback when EACH separate async operation completes.  That's how the async library knows when all three async operations are done.  You aren't calling it at all.  Also, for help in combining the results, you need to show us what an individual result looks like.

Comment: Also, in your `fetchA` function, it does you no good to `throw` inside an async callback.  That `throw` just goes into the internals of the `connection.query()` code and gets lost there.  It doesn't go anywhere you could catch it so your async code will just get stuck because the callback is never called.  You need to return the error through your callback in the typical node.js callback calling convention.  This type of error handling is actually where promises makes things a lot easier.

Comment: @jfriend00 The waterfall is to just get the connection and pass it to the parallel calls below. The connection is getting generated fine and queries are also getting executed. The only issue is getting the combined variable out of the parallel scope.

Comment: You're still not calling the callback passed to each task in `async.parallel()`.  Thus the async library will never know when those tasks are done.  Also, no reason to use `async.waterfall()` with a just two consecutive tasks.  Just use the completion callback of the first to execute the second.